# Apache Cordova app opening from a link

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I would like to ask a functionality if it is possible with apache Cordova. We would like to send a message to our user ( a text message) which contains a link . If user clicks on the link then it will open our Apache Cordova app .. we can initiate a activity on our app once it is open

Comment: https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Comment: Thank You , I will give it a try ..